# How to do a nested query get the expected result using knex?

Tags: sql, node.js, join, knex.js, subquery

There are 3 tables called `warehouses`, `agents_Warehouses`, and `agents`. `agents_warehouses` table is connected with `warehouses` table and `agents` table.

[image: agents_warehouses table]

So I need to get warehouses that **NOT IN** `agents_warehouses` table.

This is the sql query I need to do from knex.js;

```
SELECT id, name FROM `warehouses` 
WHERE id not in 
(SELECT warehouse_id as id from agents_warehouses WHERE agent_id=2)
```

How do I get my expected result using knex.js?

Comment: How would you SQL query will look like?

Comment: @felixmosh my query would like this ```SELECT id, name FROM `warehouses` WHERE id not in (SELECT warehouse_id as id from agents_warehouses WHERE agent_id=2)```

Comment: I don't see the query, can you add it to the question itself?

Comment: @felixmosh I have added the query to my question, check.

Answer (score 3):

You can build the required query with something like this:

```js
knex('warehouses')
  .columns(['id', 'name'])
  .whereNotIn('id', knex('agents_warehouses').column('warehouse_id').where('agent_id', 2));
```